# Simultaneous Wifi G and N on Different Bands

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I need to upgrade a house's routers because they are failing, but I'd also like to upgrade everything to wireless N if possible (I am buying a new router, or two if one won't end up covering the entire house)

The problem is, there is a 3rd generation iPod touch that only supports b/g, so a N-only network will not work.

I know you can keep backwards compatibility with b/g devices and an N router, but is it possible to run b/g on 2.4ghz and n on 5ghz? I though I read that was possible someplace.

If not, would the range be hurt? That's the main issue, not speed. The home internet connection isn't more than 8mbps, so I don't think speed is a huge issue. It's just a huge house that needs two wireless routers to cover the entire thing.

Comment: Depends on your router(s).  What kind of router do you have?  Knowing that may help you get an answer.  Have you looked yours up with the manufacturer to see if that ability is supported?  What have you tried already?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I'm looking to buy a new one, so it's not an issue of *how*, but if it can be done with current routers on the market. I thought I heard that some routers were capable of this, but I don't remember for sure.

Comment: Most N routers are backwards compatible with b/g. However on some it will slow everything down if any one client doesn't use n -- read the specs is all you can do.

Answer (score 6):

I believe you are looking for a "Simultaneous Dual-Band Router".

> Some newer 802.11n Wi-Fi routers also allow simultaneous dual band
>   communication with both 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz clients. By supplying
>   separate network bandwidth for each of the two types of links, these
>   routers provide maximum flexibility in setting up a home network. For
>   example, older 802.11b/g clients can be set to run on the 2.4 GHz side
>   of a simultaneous dual-band router without impacting the performance
>   of 802.11n clients running at 5 GHz.

- [Source of quote](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/wireless80211/f/dual-band-wireless.htm)
- [More info](http://www.netgear.com/landing/dual-band.aspx)
- [More info](http://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia_term/0,1237,t=abg+router&i=58499,00.asp)

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is, there is a 3rd generation iPod touch that only supports b/g, so a N-only network will not work.

Yes it will, it will just not reap the benefits of N.

> I know you can keep backwards compatibility with b/g devices and an N router, but is it possible to run b/g on 2.4ghz and n on 5ghz?

Assuming you have a router with both 2.4GHz and 5.0GHz radios, you can have signals transmitted on both frequencies; you will have two SSID's broadcasted.

> If not, would the range be hurt?

There is not much point to running on 5.0GHz if you are not concerned about speed. You may actually lose range by running on 5.0GHz.

[Choosing the right spectrum for 802.11n](http://www.wireless-nets.com/resources/tutorials/choose_802.11n_spectrum.html)